# I am trying to add a time variable to this PHP code and it is not working

Tags: php, function, date

In the code below, I am trying to return different results based on how long the user's account has been active. If their account is one day or older/return you_upgraded but if less than 1 day/return you_upgraded. I am very new to PHP so please be kind :)

```
<?php 
$acct_type = $db['user']['acct_type']; 
$type_name = $user_acct_type['type_name'];
$now = new \DateTime();
$join = $db['user']['date_joined']; 
$time = ($now - $joined);
if($acct_type == 1 OR $acct_type == 2 OR $acct_type == 3) && ($time -> days => 1){?>
<h3><?php echo $db['lang']['you_upgraded'];?></h3>
<?php }else{?>
<h3><?php echo $db['lang']['under_review'];?></h3>
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this to get no of days:

```
<?php
$today = new Datetime();

//assuming database date
$dbdate = new Datetime('2020-08-20');
$diff = $today->diff($dbdate);
$days= $diff->days;

?>
```

Comment: I think it is getting close. I'm not sure the $dbdate = new Datetime('2020-08-20') will work because each account will have a different date. I need the $dbdate to be pulled from DB.

Comment: no i assumed the date , because the date was not mentioned, replace it with your database date that was what I meant , in your case $join

Comment: I tried putting $dbdate=$db['user']['date_joined']; but it didn't work. could that be because the format of the data in db is Y-m-d H:i:s and the $today is only Y-m-d?

Comment: I did try to. I put this... date_format($dbdate, "Y-m-d") but it error..... Sorry. I'm not very good with PHP:(

Comment: can you try `$dbdate=new Datetime($db['user']['date_joined']);$actual=$dbdate->format('Y-m-d');`

Comment: One last question, If I did want to use hours instead of days would I just change remove the "format" portion and write a new variable $hours= $diff->hours;

Comment: you can get hours like this `($diff->days * 24) + $diff->h;`

Comment: so $hours=($diff->days * 24) + $diff->h;